# ForEach in Grunt task configuration

Tags: gruntjs

I am working on a Gruntfile configuration. I need to loop through all of the files that match 
the pattern defined in my templates variable as shown here:

```
module.exports = {
    templates: {
        all: ['src/templates/**/*.html*’]
    }
};
```

I need each of those files to be used as values in an array called ‘files’ on my ‘swapper’ target defined here:

```
task-config :{
  swapper : {
    files: { 
      // foreach (file in templates) {
      //   ‘destination/‘ + “‘“ + file.ToString() + “‘“ : ‘file.ToString()’
      //   if (isNotLastFile()) {
      //      appendComma()
      //   }
      // }
   },
   tasks: ['jshint:ignore_warning:test' ],
     options: {
       encodeSpecialChars: true
     }
  }
}
```

I’m having a hard time getting the syntax correct.  Is it even possible to do what I’m trying in Grunt? Or, do I need to go at this a different way?

Thanks

Comment: If you would like a more programmable situation you should look at Gulp.  It's a task runner just like Grunt, but in regular node/js code.

Comment: @Dylan Gruntfiles are written in javascript using regular node.js code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIFEs work great for this (despite what some people think, Gruntfiles are javascript and written using Node.js):

```
"task-config": {
  swapper : {
    files: (function() {
      var templates = require('./templates.js').templates;
      var out = {};
      Object.keys(templates).forEach(function(key) {
        var val = templates[key];
        // Do something with key/val to determine the dest/src
        var dest = 'destination/' + someHowDetermineYourDestination(val);
        out[dest] = val;
      });
      // Return the computed object
      return out;
    }())
  },
},
```

Check out this article for more information about IIFEs: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

It's likely you don't need the IIFE though. But rather just use the `expand` option:

```
"task-config": {
  swapper : {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'src/templates/',
    src: ['**/*.html'],
    dest: 'destination/',
  },
},
```

This will run the task on every file within `src/templates` and output, including sub-folders to the `destination/` folder.

See this section of the Grunt docs for more info: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically